# Ubuntu 16.04 install gnome desktop error unmet dependencies

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome

I am trying to install gnome desktop for ubuntu 16.04 from this PPA `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` but i am getting the following errors :

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-gnome-desktop : Depends: adwaita-icon-theme-full but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gdm3 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-documents but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-session but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-shell but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gnome-shell-extensions but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: tracker but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-music but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: gnome-photos but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
                        Recommends: libreoffice-style-tango but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried `install -f` but it is not solving the problem !

Comment: Try `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: I have tried it and i also try `sudo apt dist-upgrade` !

Comment: According to Gnome3 Team (https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3), "this PPA is no longer updated for releases older than Ubuntu 17.04. If you are using an older release, please ppa-purge this PPA and consider upgrading to a newer Ubuntu release."